# Twilio IpMessagingClient becoming null whenever I restart the app

Tags: android, twilio

When I have integrated Twilio ip messaging in my app, IPMessaging client becoming null whenever I restart or Pause my app.I am getting BasicIPmessaging client from Application . I followed quickstarter project in the below link https://github.com/twilio/ip-demo-android/tree/master/ip-messaging-demo-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If have `new BasicIPMEssgaingClient` on the application class under `onCreate`, it should not be recreated until onCreate is called again. I.e.

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    TwilioApplication.instance = this;
    basicClient = new BasicIPMessagingClient(getApplicationContext());
}
```

This should make sure the variable has a value assigned for the entire lifecycle of the application. Now, you haven't posted any of your code, so i can't see what you're doing, but thought I'd point out that BasicIPMessagingClient is meant to be a singleton, and should be accessed through:

```
"TwilioApplication.get().getBasicClient().getIpMessagingClient();
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you. I have added this.It is working fine when I pause the app and resumes.But when I restart it it is becoming null.

Comment: When you say restart, do you mean force closing the app, or just leaving it in background?

Comment: not force closing.Just closing the app .Swiping from right to left from list of opened apps .

Comment: Ok, then I'm confused. What do you mean with "it's working fine when I pause the app"? When you go from one app to another, you are pausing the app. It would only restart if you're killing the app and starting it again, but then that's expected, and onCreate should be called again.

Comment: thank you.Its my mistake only.I didn't call login() method 
    `public void login(final String username, final String url, final LoginListener listener) {
    }` Now I am calling when I opens the app. Is it correct way ?